# How to compile cpp source to full static binary and except for: libc, libpthread, libdl, libstdc++, and libm

Tags: c++, compilation, cross-compiling

I want to compile a binary linux to full static, But I always fail with this configuration:

```
CFLAGS="--static" CPPFLAGS="-I/home/alan/arm/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/include" LDFLAGS="-L/home/alan/arm/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc//usr/lib" LIBS="-lcrypt -ldl -lpthread -lm -lc -lstdc++" CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc AR=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar CXX=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ ./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/home/alan/armbin/test --without-pcre --without-zlib --without-bzip2 --without-openssl --disable-ipv6 --enable-static
```

But I always get warning dlopen, gethostbyname, etc. If I not except libc, libm, etc to shared. I get warning approximately as below:

```
warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`.

[Source](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/statical-linking-943505/).

Comment: I'm on the edge of my seat!

Answer (score 0):

Your link command should look like this:
g++ objectFiles $(CFLAGS) -o executable -Wl,-Bstatic -L/path/to/static/lib1/ -ls1 -L/path/to/static/lib2 -ls2 -Wl,-Bdynamic

You only have to explicitly call the static libraries libs1.a, libs2.a . The shared system libraries you are referring to (libc.so, libpthreads.so, libm.so, libdl.so, libstdc++.so etc.) should be found implicitly by your linker and are affected by -Wl, -Bdynamic. You don't have to pass them explicitly. Try and do a 
"ldd executable" to see the dynamic dependencies.